# iOS: Get the length of the song from parse

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have uploaded few files on parse framework and I am live streaming those files and play them in AVPlayer.

```
let url = currentAudioPath
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
player1 = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
player1.rate = 1.0;
self.configurePlayer()
player1.play()
```

I have not downloaded the entire file at once. But is there a way to retrieve the length of the song?

Answer (score 0):

"`AVPlayerItem`" has a ["`.duration`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/duration) that might help you.

Look at the notes though: You won't be able to get the duration "until the status of the AVPlayerItem is AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay."  You could also set a KVO on the property so you could update your UI once the item duration is determined by the AVFoundation layer.